# Find and replace in bash for variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, debian

I am using bash and I was wondering if there is a nice way to do a find and replace on a file using bash. In my case I want to turn a placeholder variable into the orignal variable, working with any number of different variables. For example:

```
"$PLACEHOLDER_ABC" -> $ABC 
"$PLACEHOLDER_123" -> $123 
"$PLACEHOLDER_qwe" -> $qwe
```

I am not sure where to start, should I be using find, sed, a while loop, or all of the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
sed 's/\$PLACEHOLDER_/\$/g' file
```

would remove `PLACEHOLDER_` everywhere it is found after a dollar sign, effectively truncating the parameter expansion where it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at "m4" the macro processor. The manpages are [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/). It is included in most Linux/Unix distros.

Here is a little example:

```
define(`hello', `Hello, World')
hello, welcome to m4!
```

If we run this file through m4 with the command

```
m4 sample.m4 > sample.txt
```

it produces the following output:

```
Hello, World, welcome to m4!
```

Answer (score 0):

find filename -exec sed -i 's/\$PLACEHOLDER_/\$/g' {} \;